# Конфликтуют заголовочные файлы

Tags: файлы, c++, visual-c++

Есть некий исходный файл `core.cpp` (в составе решения vc++) с таким содержанием:

```
#include "core.h"    
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>    
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

2-3 - библиотеки GDI+, последние три - WinSock. При запуске компилятора вот такие  ошибки:

```
error C3861: WSASetLastError: идентификатор не найден   ws2tcpip.h  649
error C3861: WSASetLastError: идентификатор не найден   ws2tcpip.h  703
error C3861: WSASetLastError: идентификатор не найден   ws2tcpip.h  742 
error C3861: WSASetLastError: идентификатор не найден   ws2tcpip.h  749 
error C3861: WSASetLastError: идентификатор не найден   ws2tcpip.h  793
error C3861: WSASetLastError: идентификатор не найден   ws2tcpip.h  800
error C3861: WSASetLastError: идентификатор не найден   ws2tcpip.h  841
error C3861: WSASetLastError: идентификатор не найден   ws2tcpip.h  848
error C2079: "sockaddr_gen::Address" использует неопределенный struct "sockaddr"    80  
error C2079: "sockaddr_gen::AddressIn" использует неопределенный struct "sockaddr_in"
```

и ещё 140 таких ошибок...

Но вот если убрать заголовочные файлы GDI+ и оставить `WinSock` - то всё компилируется без ошибок! И если наоборот - оставить только GDI+ - тоже все работает! Такое ощущение, что эти  заголовочные файлы несовместимы друг с другом или испорчены. Но как быть? Мне нужны обе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выстройте заголовочные файлы в таком порядке:

```
#include "core.h" 
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Эта проблема возникает если включить `windows.h` перед `winsock2.h`, из-за того, что `windows.h` ключается `winsock.h`. У Вас `objidl.h` включает `windows.h`.

Comment: @atwice, а как сделать так, чтобы их можно было подключать в произвольном порядке?

Comment: @ололо, есть такой метод: перед включением `windows.h` определить макрос `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`. Тогда из `windows.h` только минимум включается.

    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <objidl.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>

Ок.